# Access an array with a counter in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to access the access and compare the data in two arrays, repeatedly. Something like this:

```
function validate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numofqs; i++) {
        if (useranswer[i] == answer[i]) {
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak1589/a8ec3y9n/1/)

Comment: You weren't invoking your function. Here is an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/1rf1s9sr/). It works with a couple slight modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple edits to your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak1589/a8ec3y9n/1/)

Changed loop maximum to be the number of items in your answers array (unless this needs to be a separate variable for some reason...)

```
for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
```

Corrected typo (user**A**nswer, not user**a**nswer)

```
if (userAnswer[i] == answer[i]) {
```

Called validate method before checking score

```
validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code in jsfiddle. In my opinion, it should be:

```
var score = 0;
var userAnswer = ["bob", "bla", "explosion"];
var answer = ["fire", "chemicals", "explosion"];

(function validate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswer[i] && userAnswer[i] === answer[i]) {
            score++;
        }
    }
})();

alert(score);
```